# Make a target run once at the Solution level in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I need a set of tasks that need to be executed exactly once for the entire solution. This will run tasks that will modify each project to run a separate set of tasks for each project. We had done this earlier using a separate project to the solution which had the solution level tasks, but we want to move away from that. Has anyone done this or does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Solution files are not in MSBuild format they are not easily extended or customized. If you want more control over the build process you would have to create a "driver" msbuild file which would replace your solution file. Inside this driver file you would build all the projects that you needed and perform some additional tasks. You would do this using the [MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx). Here is a sample showing how to build more than 1 project.

```
<Project ...>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Projects Include="proj01.csproj"/>
        <Projects Include="proj02.csproj"/>
        <Projects Include="proj03.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="BuildAll">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(Projects)" BuildInParallel="true" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

So in your case you would just execute the tasks before you build the projects. Also note that I specified the value true for the `BuildInParallel` indicating that MSBuild can try and build more than one project at once.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I believe this will also work if I want to perform some additional tasks before building the projects? (And those additional tasks will be modifying the projects themselves.)

Comment: Creating these build files is a very common scenario. A lot of people prefer writing these types of build files instead using the solution for production builds. In my case I only use solution files for Visual Studio, never for actual builds.

Comment: Sayed in this approach say if my project 1 depends on project 2 then wouldn't msbuild build my project 2 twice thus delaying the build process?

Comment: MSBuild has incremental build so it should know it's already built and up to date.

Comment: Thanks @SayedIbrahimHashimi I am going to try this and see how this pans out. I do "a lot" of MSBuild customizations in my job so these tips are always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to have a single target that dispatches to an MSBuild invoked target with as many Global properties removed as possible. My team have a target in the InitialTargets of a Directory.Build.props Import'ed props file - something like:

```xml
<Target Name="Prebuild">
  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)"
           Targets="PrebuildWorker"
           RemoveProperties="Configuration;Platform;TargetFramework;BuildProjectReferences" />
</Target>
```

Since MSBuild appears to synchronize parallel builds on the `{project file, global properties, target}` set, then by removing all of the properties you can synchronize the build and run it once for all projects being built. The downside: you have to maintain the `RemoveProperties` attribute - MSBuild doesn't have a way to remove all global properties. If something in the build issues a new `MSBuild` task with a custom property specified, then you'll get a second instance of the Target invoked.

And - of course - your build will be synchronized on this target. You could try hooking the target up by setting, say, `CompileDependsOn` to depend on the `Prebuild` target, to allow independent progress in the build. But to have the target run early and ubiquitously using InitialTargets seems like the better option.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a project then add that with `PrivateAsset=all` so the project is a development only dependency. If you want to simplify this you can add a `Directory.Build.props` to your solution and add this reference to all of your projects in the solution.  Any task executed within this project will only run once per build execution no matter if you build targeted projects or the solution as whole.  This does not require any special build commands being added to your build pipeline and will even work from within visual studio with no additional changes for your solution.

I created an example project and posted it on GitHub to show this technique.

[BuildFirstOnce](https://github.com/OutOfBandDevelopment/BuildFirstOnce/tree/main/src)