# Include .sln file in MsBuild file?

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to build Visual Studio project from `.msbuild` file. The idea is to do some things before the build, then execute build of `.sln` from the same place.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildClient" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <Tools>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\tools</Tools>
    <NugetExe>$(Tools)\nuget\nuget.exe</NugetExe>
    <ClientFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\src\Client</ClientFolder>
    <ClientSolution>$(ClientFolder)\ClientProject.sln</ClientSolution>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BuildClient">
    <!--Restore Nuget-->
    <Message Text="Starting Restoring Nuget Packages" />
    <Exec Command=" $(NugetExe) restore $(ClientSolution)" />
    <Message Text="Finished Restoring Nuget Packages" />


    <Import Project="$(ClientSolution)" />

    <!--build project-->
  </Target>
</Project>
```

But line with `<Import>` is underlined in VS, saying import should be on level up, not within `<Target>`. When I move `<Import>` a level up as suggested I get an execution error:

```
errorMSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid.
```

Any idea how to build whole project without major rewriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me! the solution turns out to be very simple:

```
<MSBuild Projects="..\..\MySolution.sln" "/>
```

This did the trick with executing the build on `.sln` file

I got the pointer from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2456075/809357).